# How to replace a substring with multiple strings

Tags: python

I'm setting up a graphical calculator and I need to calculate a list of y values from multiple given x values. Like for example the equation is 10x+5. I set the view window as -10 to 10. I need to find a way to calculate 10(-10)+5 all the way up to 10(10)+5.

In order to do that I would need to find a way to replace x with a list of integers. How can I achieve that?

replace() doesn't work because it only accepts str and not lists.

`equation.replace('x', xValues)`

Comment: `10(-10)+5` is a `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`. This problem is actually much harder than simple text substitution. You need to either force the user to use the explicit multiplication symbol (`*`) or create your own expression parser.

Answer (score 0):

`[equation.replace('x', y) for y in xValues]` use list comprehension for it

Comment: Please avoid code only answer. Provide some context and explain what the code does.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply apply the replace function to a list of values you are interested in:

```
xValues = range(-10, 11)
equation = "10*x+5"
result = [equation.replace("x", str(v)) for v in xValues]
```

Note that replace take both string arguments, so you need to convert your to-replace value to string first.

Above will give you a list of all expressions:

```
['10*-10+5',
 '10*-9+5',
 '10*-8+5',
 '10*-7+5',
 '10*-6+5',
 '10*-5+5',
 '10*-4+5',
 '10*-3+5',
 '10*-2+5',
 '10*-1+5',
 '10*0+5',
 '10*1+5',
 '10*2+5',
 '10*3+5',
 '10*4+5',
 '10*5+5',
 '10*6+5',
 '10*7+5',
 '10*8+5',
 '10*9+5',
 '10*10+5']
```

Answer (score 0):

loop through the values:

```
for x in range(-10, 11):
  print(10*x + 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple for loop

```
for i in range(-10,11): #upper limit is 11 because it exclude it and run till 10
    print((10*i)+5)     #if you want answer only
    print("10 * "+str(i)+" + 5") #if you want equation
    print("10 * "+str(i)+" + 5",(10*i)+5) #if you want both equation with answer
```

remove comment before use